# What does exactly "memory is accountable" mean?

Tags: linux, memory

I understand that "accounted memory" means memory that is ensured to be always commited, that means: every page of the VMA is either in RAM or swap, so every page must be allocated.

However, if I `cat /proc/self/smaps`, I can see that the `[heap]` has the `ac` flag (I have ommited the irrelevant fields from the output):

```
<addr> rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
Size:                132 kB
Rss:                   8 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         8 kB
Referenced:            8 kB
Anonymous:             8 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
THPeligible:    0
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me ac sd
```

However, the VMA has a size of 132 kB, but only 8kb are resident, and so there is 124kB that are not commited yet.

What does `ac` means in this context? The `man proc` says that `ac` means "the area is accountable", but I don't really know what does mean.

Answer (score 1):

I believe "ac" mapped VMAs are counting toward the OOM-killer weight. E.g. glibc stack guards are not marked with ac, so they don't count.